# How can I implement paging for a custom query plugin which displays data from an external API?

Tags: 8, views, paging, plugins

Hi I have a requirement to display the data from external api but should not be imported into any entities. What I did is I have written a custom view query plugin which displays the data from external api. What I did is I have used the GuzzleHttp Client to get the data. Here is how my service looks like

```
namespace Drupal\***_services;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;

class NewsBlogsClient {

  /**
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\Client
   */
  protected $client;

  /**
   * NewsBlogsClient constructor.
   *
   * @param $http_client_factory \Drupal\Core\Http\ClientFactory
   */
  public function __construct($http_client_factory) {
    $this->client = $http_client_factory->fromOptions([
      'base_uri' => 'https://****************/',
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Get all the news.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function getNews() {
    $response = $this->client->get('****');

    $data = Json::decode($response->getBody());

    return $data;
  }

  /**
   * Get all the blogs.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function getBlogs() {
    $response = $this->client->get('****');

    $data = Json::decode($response->getBody());

    return $data;
  }

}
```

I called the service into my plugin query and mapped it to the view fields that I have created using hook_views_data(). Here is how my plugin query looks like.

```
namespace Drupal\****\Plugin\views\query;

use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\ResultRow;
use Drupal\views\Annotation\ViewsQuery;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

/**
 * Views query plugin which wraps calls to the *** API in order to
 * expose the results to views.
 *
 * @ViewsQuery(
 *   id = "news",
 *   title = @Translation("News"),
 *   help = @Translation("Query against the API.")
 * )
 */
class News extends QueryPluginBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\*****\NewsBlogsClient
   */
  protected $newsBlogsClient;

  /**
   * FeaturedNews constructor.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param $plugin_id
   * @param $plugin_definition
   * @param $newsBlogsClient \Drupal\****\NewsBlogsClient
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $news_blogs_client) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->newsBlogsClient = $news_blogs_client;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('news_blogs_client')
    );
  }

  /**
   *
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  public function execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
    $index = 0;
    if ($news_items = $this->newsBlogsClient->getNews()) {
      foreach ($news_items as $news_item) {
        $row['title'] = $news_item['title'];
        $row['link'] = $news_item['view_node'];
        $date = $news_item['field_published_date'];
        $dateTime = new DrupalDateTime($date);
        $timestamp = $dateTime->format('U');
        $row['pubdate'] = $timestamp;
        $row['summary'] = $news_item['field_short_description'];
        $row['thumbnail'] = $news_item['uri'];
        // 'index' key is required.
        $row['index'] = $index++;
        $view->result[] = new ResultRow($row);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Ensures a table exists in the query.
   *
   * This replicates the interface of Views' default SQL backend to simplify
   * the Views integration of the API. Since the API has no
   * concept of "tables", this method implementation does nothing. If you are
   * writing API-specific Views code, there is therefore no reason at all
   * to call this method.
   * See https://www.drupal.org/node/2484565 for more information.
   *
   * @return string
   *   An empty string.
   */
  public function ensureTable($table, $relationship = NULL) {
    return '';
  }

  /**
   * Adds a field to the table. In our case, the API has no
   * notion of limiting the fields that come back, so tracking a list
   * of fields to fetch is irrelevant for us. Hence this function body is more
   * or less empty and it serves only to satisfy handlers that may assume an
   * addField method is present b/c they were written against Views' default SQL
   * backend.
   *
   * This replicates the interface of Views' default SQL backend to simplify
   * the Views integration of the API.
   *
   * @param string $table
   *   NULL in most cases, we could probably remove this altogether.
   * @param string $field
   *   The name of the metric/dimension/field to add.
   * @param string $alias
   *   Probably could get rid of this too.
   * @param array $params
   *   Probably could get rid of this too.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The name that this field can be referred to as.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::addField()
   */
  public function addField($table, $field, $alias = '', $params = array()) {
    return $field;
  }
}
```

Everything is working great. I can display and control the data through views. The only missing thing is paging. The API is also from another Drupal application which supports pagination. I also need to setup a pager for this query. Tried lot of things but didn't work. I don't know how actually a view pager works. Can anyone explain and provide me any example snippet or code to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some pager handling that's required. There isn't a great example of this, except to try to follow along with what `\Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql` does, translating the things that are SQL specific into things that are relevant for your API.

In your implementation of `\Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase::execute` you need to first trigger the preExecute phase of the pager setup. Looking at the `\Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql` implementation, here's what that class does:

```php
// Let the pager modify the query to add limits.
$view->pager->preExecute($query);

if (!empty($this->limit) || !empty($this->offset)) {
  // We can't have an offset without a limit, so provide a very large limit instead.
  $limit = intval(!empty($this->limit) ? $this->limit : 999999);
  $offset = intval(!empty($this->offset) ? $this->offset : 0);
  $query->range($offset, $limit);
}
```

Obviously the line `$query->range($offset, $limit);` isn't applicable to your use case, b/c here `\Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql` is concerned with building up a SQL query. The rest is applicable almost verbatium. With the above code you have a `$limit` and `$offset` per the configuration (and/or active query string / exposed pager) of your view that you can then apply to your API call to get back a paged result. That's the key, the views module won't page the `$view->result` array for you. It's up to you to use the `$offset` and `$limit` to apply paging yourself. Ideally your API supports paging and you can translate `$offset` and `$limit` to match what the API wants, or if your lucky just use them directly. Alternatively, you would need to `array_slice` your full array of results back from the API.

Hope that helps.